# Trying phppgadmin docker container to view postgres database on host: it says login failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, phppgadmin

I want to view the host postgresql with phppgadmin docker container

My host is archlinux and with postgresql server running on it.

I have /var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = "*"
```

and

/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           password
```

I want to view the postgresql tables. So i using phppgadmin docker with the following command

```
docker run --name='phppgadmin' --rm \
                --publish=8888:80 \
                -e PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST="127.0.0.1" \
                dockage/phppgadmin:latest
```

Now i can open the phppgadmin from `127.0.0.1:8888/phppgadmin`

But when i try to login it says `login failed`

I have a django project on my host using the using hosts postgresql. That works well with the settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': ‘<db_name>’,
        'USER': '<db_username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }

}
```

Also my netstat output on host

```
$ netstat -nrv                                         
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-1c7e732767f4
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-17604ffc4858
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

on my docker container

```
$ netstat -nrv
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

From `netstat -nrv` on my phppgadmin docker container

```
$ netstat -nrv
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

So the ip address of the host is `172.17.0.1`

Change `PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST="127.0.0.1"` to `PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST="172.17.0.1"`

```
docker run --name='phppgadmin' --rm \
                --publish=8888:80 \
                -e PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST="172.17.0.1" \
                dockage/phppgadmin:latest
```

with:

I have /var/lib/postgres/data/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = "localhost,127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1"
```

and

/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           md5
```

Open `127.0.0.1:8888/phppgadmin` and login with non Superuser

For Superuser its still not working.